# Can we access any sound playing in any iphone application through my application and apply equalizer

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, equalizer

I know app can import sound and video files in the application and apply any equalizer to the sound on playing. But my question is can we make an iOS application which access any sound playing the iphone so that we can make some equalizer changes according to user requirements which probably should be remain same if user is listening music on Music and or watching video on Youtube ?

Comment: can i know reason for downvote ?

Comment: Your app is sandboxed, it does not have access to global audio, it only knows of any  audio played by your app. so no, you cannot do it

Comment: Ok @Scriptable Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

*App Sandbox is an access control technology provided in macOS, enforced at the kernel level. It is designed to contain damage to the system and the user’s data if an app becomes compromised. Apps distributed through the Mac App Store must adopt App Sandbox. Apps signed and distributed outside of the Mac App Store with Developer ID can (and in most cases should) use App Sandbox as well.*

**As mention in above comment, iOS application can access only in its Sandbox resource so capturing audio from other application cannot be possible** [image: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html]

For more info
[About App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cann't access because of sandbox security of application